# Is there a symbol for exponentiation?

Tags: notation

When we define a structure, let's say a group, we write $(G ,\oplus )$ for an operation $\oplus$. In case I want to define a structure with operation exponentiation I just define the $\oplus$ so that $a \oplus b = a^b$, which is what I have done until now. But a curiosity of mine is, if there exists, or if it ever existed, a symbolic representation of exponentiation.

Thus, have you ever come across a symbol for exponentiation?

Comment: What about the up arrow $\uparrow$ ?

Comment: I don't think you can define a group under the operation exponentiation — it's not associative.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the caret ( ^ ) symbol and (as Yves mentioned) the up arrow (  ↑ ) is used for exponentation.

Comment: I suppose, after reading the Wikipedia article on the arrow notation, that this latter is usually preferred to the first one, or is it just a matter of *personal* preference?

Comment: Where did you read it? @E.S.L.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the use of the caret in order to express exponentiation comes from programming languages implementation, whereas the up-arrow is a more formal version of it. I might be wrong, I am just conjecturing.

Comment: I have seen both in programming.

Comment: Here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret#Surrogate_symbol_for_superscript_and_exponentiation <-Usage of caret

Answer (score 1):

The caret (^) is most common, but in some programming languages (such as python) the double asterisk (**) is used.